# SKScene vertically squashed

Tags: ios, storyboard, sprite-kit, skscene

My SKScene is vertically squashed. I have added an SKEmitterNode, but this is clearly being squished and I have no idea why.

I have another emitter in another scene which is not doing this and all the code appears to be exactly the same.

Normal:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqbR1.png)

Squashed:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfhgm.png)

Edit:

The code is IDENTICAL for both.

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

Comment: Did you start from the Xcode "SpriteKit Game" template? And if so have you seen [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1) Ray Wenderlich tutorial? Scroll down to Getting Started and there's a bit about moving this code from viewDidLoad to viewWillLayoutSubviews to make sure the scene gets the correct bounds.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used the SpriteKit template, I just created the scene in viewWillLayoutSubviews and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by Simon Jenkins, moving the layout code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` instead of `viewDidLoad()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scaleMode` property seems off.

Try `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;` or `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;` depending on your requirements.

Comment: Tried it, but it still is being squashed. This confuses me

Comment: Hm, a bit of a mystery then. Could you please update your question with the code where you create the two scenes?